# Pagerank of different pages - new twitter?

Tags: twitter, pagerank

How new twitter manage to make every page of users has 9 pagerank? In the old one each page was perceived as a different page and therefore has different pageranks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They've redirected http://twitter.com/ceejayoz to http://twitter.com/#!/ceejayoz, which is actually just http://twitter.com/ to a search engine. There are indexable pages behind the scenes (URLs like http://twitter.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/ceejayoz), but you don't see them.

The intent isn't to game PageRank, that's just a side effect of the AJAX URLs they're using.